# Update last login session in php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo

I am using this code to update the user's last login time and end their session when they click "logout". From there the user will be directed to the index.php page. The last login time is now updating. Please help.

```
<?php
session_start();  

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "account";

     try {
     $db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}",$db_user,$db_pass);
     $db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 $stmt = $db_conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET lastlogin = :lastlogin  WHERE ID = :ID");

       
$stmt->bindParam(':lastlogin', $time); 
$stmt->bindParam(':ID', $_SESSION['ID']); 


$time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
//$ID = $_SESSION['ID'];

    $stmt->execute();
    session_destroy();
    header('location:index.php');   

    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
    }
$db_conn = null;

?>
```

Comment: Why not just use mysql's time? `now()`..

Comment: Good luck, I'm on to another thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define $time before you use it:

```
$time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$id = $_SESSION['ID'];
$stmt->bindParam(':lastlogin', $time); 
$stmt->bindParam(':ID', $id);
```

make sure you have value in `$_SESSION['ID']`

Comment: The doc doesn't support that statement, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php. See example 1.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this and it worked fine

```
<?php
session_start();  

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "account";
     try {
       $time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
       $username = $_SESSION['username'];

     $db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}",$db_user,$db_pass);
     $db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 $stmt = $db_conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET lastlogin = :lastlogin WHERE username = '$username'");
 $stmt->bindParam(':lastlogin', $time); 
 //$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_SESSION['username']); 
 $stmt->execute();
   session_destroy();
   header('location:index.php');    


    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
    }
$db_conn = null;


?>
```

Comment: Would you indicate what in this answer has changed from the original post? That would be helpful to readers who might be able to learn from it in the future. (You can accept this answer too, by clicking on the tick mark to the left of it - accepting ones own answers is fine here).